# Let $F$ be a field. (a) If $1 + 1 = 0$, show that $a + a = 0$ for all $a \in F$. (b) If $a + a = 0$ for some $a \neq 0$, show that $1 + 1 = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field.
>
> (a) If $1 + 1 = 0$, show that $a + a = 0$ for all $a \in F$.
>
> (b) If $a + a = 0$ for some $a \neq 0$, show that $1 + 1 = 0$

I have found proof's for $1+1=0$ but I am not sure if it is the right proof for this question.
I am a bit unsure as to that the question is asking, do I assume $F$ is a field $\{0,1\}$?
anyone who can show me the answer and how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe your attempt?

Comment: Should "a 6= O" be $a \neq 0$ in first line?

Comment: The problem is I am very new to these sort of proofs and way of thinking and don't have anyone to help me.

Comment: my attempt was to jsut verify the field axioms and set 1+1=0 but I really am clueless

Comment: yes it should be a isnt equal to 0

Comment: In fact, you just need to use some field axioms. An observation: $\{0,1\}$ is not a field try to check why. $F$ is an arbitrary field where $0$ is the neutral element of addition and $1$ is the neutral element of product.

Comment: @Lucas Corrêa.  Why do you say $\ \{0,1\}\ $ is not a field?   I presume you mean it's not a field under normal addition and multiplication of integers.  But it's not obvious (at least, not to me) that the OP was assuming those definitions, and with the definitions of addition and multiplication implied by the conditions he states, it becomes the field $\ GF\left(2\right)\ $. He cannot, of course, assume that $\ F\ $ *is* that field, since it might be some other field of characteristic 2.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, you're right! I presume that the operations were the usuals by the type of the question (in general, questions about field axioms use char $0$ and the usual operations). But formally, you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (a): Given $1+1=0,$ multiply by $a$ and apply distributive law. Also need that $a\cdot 0=0$ for any $a$ but that should be a lemma early on [also can be proved fairly easily from field axioms].

Comment: so I just say that a(1 + 1) = a . 0  
distributivity

Comment: then I jsut use the field axiom for anything times 1 is itself?

Comment: @johnsmith That seems like a very reasonable way to do it.

Comment: @johnsmith Yes, use also $a\cdot 1=a.$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy provided by the field axioms; specifically, if $a,b,c\in F$ where $(F,+,\cdot)$ is a field, then $a\cdot(b+c)= a\cdot b+a\cdot c$.  Using this we have

$$1+1=0$$
$$a\cdot(1+1)=a\cdot 0$$
$$a\cdot 1+a\cdot 1=0$$

$$a+a=0$$

Note that all these steps are reversible, because in a field all non-zero elements are units, i.e., have an inverse, and for it to be a field it must be a domain so cancellation law must hold. Since all steps are reversible, this also answers $(b).$

Comment: I'd say $a\cdot 0 = 0$ is more elementary then $a(-a) = - a^2$. How would you prove $(-1)\cdot a = - a$ without $a\cdot 0 = 0$?

Comment: @Ennar You're right, I'll just assume $a\cdot 0=0$

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to show the given relations . And we are gonna work with some basic properties of a field. Let( F ,+, .) Is our field .
Now it's given, 1+1=0.
Now if , a belongs to F then by using the property, 
a.(b+c)=a.b+a.c , for all , a,b,c belongs to F , we can write,

a.(1+1)=a.1+a.1 = a+a , as '1' is multiplicative identity. 
So, a+a=0 ,as a.0=0 ....(p)

[ a.0= 0 because,
0+0=0 , as 0 is additive identity.
Now  if a belongs to F then,
a.0 +a.0=a.0
Now as a belongs to F , -a belongs to F , as it's the additive inverse.
So , -a.0+a.0+a.0=-a.0+a.0
Or, a.0=0 ]

Now for some a≠0 , if a belongs to F, the (1/a) belongs to F as (1/a) is multiplicative inverse of a .
Now , as   a+a=0 , by using a.(b+c)=a.b+a.c , we can write (1/a).(a+a)= a.1/a+a.1/a .
As, a.1/a=1 , then

1+1=0.

Answer (score 0):

> I am a bit unsure as to that the question is asking, do I assume $F$ is a field $\{0,1\}$?

Let's read through the requirements of the problem carefully. All that is given to us is: "Let $F$ be a field." So we know $F$ is a field -- we don't know how many elements it has, but all fields at least have a zero element (which is written $0$) and a one element (which is written $1$).

> (a) If $1 + 1 = 0$, show that $a + a = 0$ for all $a \in F$.

Now for this part, it does not assume that $F = \{0,1\}$ like you said; but it's just stating a fact about $0$ and $1$, which are elements of the field. So it is stating the fact that $1 + 1 = 0$. Then we have to prove that $a + a = 0$, for any $a \in F$. To do this, try multiplying by $a$ and using the field axioms.

> (b) If $a + a = 0$ for some $a \neq 0$, show that $1 + 1 = 0$

For this part, try "dividing" by $a$ instead of multiplying. What axiom of the fields would let us divide by $a$? Remember that "dividing" really means multiplying by the multiplicative inverse.